# Protractor send keys entering undefined before user name

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, dataprovider

I am using jasmine data provider to do data driven testing..I have the following code. The code executes but however, it enters undefined infront of the user names.. the same code works when I don't use any data provider and sendKeys("username"). Please advise. I have the need to use data driven. For my rest of my tests I have implemented parallel test Method.

```
  describe('data driven tests', function() {
     var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
     var using = require('jasmine-data-provider');


    using([{val1: 'testUser1@1234.com'}, {val2: 'testUser2@1234.com'}], function (value)//changed here  {
      it('Should click on ', function() {

        browser.get('/#/');

        element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(value.val1, value.val2);
        element(by.name('password')).clear().sendKeys('password');
        element(by.id('login')).click();;

     });
      });

    });
```

Comment: Isn't `data` an array with 2 objects? I suppose accessing the values with `data.val1, data.val2` is wrong.

Comment: I changed data to value but still it is entering undefined in front of username. http://blog.jphpsf.com/2012/08/30/drying-up-your-javascript-jasmine-tests

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: I just updated the content above in my post. Instead of data, I am passing value now. I tried with json even that is not working. For some reason the organization i am in do not want parallel tests :(. Hence hunting for data driven and I need to make this work :( https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/978

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
 browser.executeScript("var editor = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;editor.setValue('{');");
```